# Java Socket Server with PHP client

Tags: java, php, serversocket

the question is totally rewritten since I have understood that previously it was really unclear.
I have created a Java Socket server with threads to accept multiple connection in order to handle php tcp requests.
The java server just for the testing purposes it reverse the string supplied from php.
Java server is hosted on a ubuntu server and the php is located on another machine.
The java server shows that php client is connected, but the php is not loading and the string is not sent.
From the codes given below what could be the mistake?

UPDATE
the problem is the received string from the Java server. I have checked with debugger and the BufferedReader is full of '\u0000' and server stops responding. The rest code and communication is working perfect.
How I can avoid those null characters or decode the string correct?

ReverseServer

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ReverseServer {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    int port = 10007;

    try (ServerSocket serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port)) {

        System.out.println("Server is listening on port " + port);

        while (true) {
            Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();
            System.out.println("New client connected");

            new ServerThread(socket).start();
        }

    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

ServerThread

```
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ServerThread extends Thread {
private Socket socket;

public ServerThread(Socket socket) {
    this.socket = socket;
}

public void run() {
    try {
        InputStream input = socket.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input));

        OutputStream output = socket.getOutputStream();
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(output, true);


        String text;

        do {
            text = reader.readLine();
            String reverseText = new StringBuilder(text).reverse().toString();
            writer.println("Server: " + reverseText);

        } while (!text.equals("bye"));

        socket.close();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        System.out.println("Server exception: " + ex.getMessage());
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}
}
```

PHP client

```
<?php

// websocket connection test
$host    = "ip_of_server";
$port    = 10007;
$message = "Hello";
echo "Message To server :".$message;
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, getprotobyname('TCP'));
$result = socket_connect($socket, $host, $port);

if ($result) {
// send string to server
socket_write($socket, $message, strlen($message)) or die("Could not send data to server\n");
// get server response
$result = socket_read($socket, 1024) or die("Could not read server response\n");
echo "Reply From Server  :" . $result;
}

socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: Use a debugger, trace through each line, see where it fails, get error code, get error message, and if you still can't figure it out - provide these details in the question...

Comment: I though about the debugger, but the server is executed from terminal and I don't know how to check it with debugger and the same applies with php (I am not familiar with xDebugger)

Comment: Just add some basic logging to a file then. And make sure PHP error reporting is switched on.

Comment: well, you should familiarize yourself. it's definitely worth the investment. a powerful IDE will make things a little easier. I recommend JetBrains' PhpStorm and IntelliJ IDEA (for the Java part)

Comment: @obe I am using phpStorm and IntelliJ, but the code on server is then written in nano, then compiled and executed from terminal (ssh connected).

Comment: On the ubuntu server I have tested a java client server app that I had created and it's working as expected. I suppose it's something from the php file

Comment: I have started all in localhost and show that the connection is ok, the issue arise when the socket_write sends the message and BufferedReader receives it as 8.8192 characters of '\u0000' 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am trying to read a line, but on the string given on the php client didn't had the carriage return symbol "\r".
Once I have put this on the string it works as expected.